# How do I run a php with a bat, vbs script with cron job

Tags: php, batch-file, vbscript, cron

I have a php script that I want to run once daily on a Windows xampp server. below is the .bat file

```
"C:\xampp\php\php.exe" - f "C:\xampp\htdocs\myScript.php"
```

I also have a vbs file that executes the batch file

```
Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WinScriptHost.Run Chr(34) & "C:\cronJob\myScript.bat" & Chr(34),0
Set WindScriptHost = Nothing
```

below is the error message I get when I run the batch file:

> ```
> C:\cronJob>"C:\xampp\php\php.exe" - f "C:\xampp\htdocs\myScript.php"
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_oci' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_oci (The specified module could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_pdo_oci.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_oci' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_oci (The specified module could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_pdo_oci.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
> PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Module 'pdo_mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
> PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO_ODBC' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Module 'PDO_ODBC' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
> PHP Warning:  Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
> Could not open input file: -
> ```

Comment: It should be `-f <file>` not `- f <file>`, shouldn't it?

Comment: fyi, "_on a Windows xampp server_" This does _not_ run _on_ a Windows XAMP server, you're "just" using the PHP executable provided by XAMP.